# Scrapy: Select specific word due to search characters in HTML Text

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I have the following HTML script where I am searching for specific words.

```
<tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Berufsbezeichnung:</th>
                <td class="gray">ExampleName</td>
            </tr>
                        <tr>
                <th>Anrede:</th>
                <td class="gray">Herrn</td>
            </tr>
                        <tr>
                <th>Name:</th>
                <td class="gray">ExampleLastName</td>
            </tr>
                        <tr>
                <th>Vorname:</th>
                <td class="gray">ExampleSurname</td>
            </tr>
            …
</tbody>
```

I want to have different variables "Berufsbezeichnung", "Anrede",... which have to be filled with the correct content. In same data sets for example "Berufsbezeichnung" is missing, so this variable has to be left empty.

I tried a scrapy script that searches for the content but it isnt working:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.css('table').extract()[0],'lxml')

for elem in soup.findAll('tr'):
    for eleme in elem.findAll('th'):
        if eleme.get_text()=='Berufsbezeichnung:':
            Berufsbezeichnung = elem.css('td.gray::text')
        if eleme.get_text()=='Anrede:':
            Anrede = elem.css('td.gray::text')
        ...
```

Does somebody has an idea or maybe also an easier way?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: at start assign default value to `Berufsbezeichnung` - it can be empty string (or None). If it doesn't find it then you will have this variable with empty/default string.

Comment: are you using `scrapy`? if yes, you don't really need bsoup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
search_by_header = '//th[contains(., "{}")]/following-sibling::td/text()'.format
Berufsbezeichnung = response..xpath(search_by_header("Berufsbezeichnung")).extract_first()
Anrede = response.xpath(search_by_header("Anrede")).extract_first()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in the @eLRuLL comment, I don't get why you use `BeautifulSoup` since scrapy have already [powerful tool available](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#selectors).

For your case, I suggest you to use simply `xpath`:

```
extracted_values = {} # Store the extracted values in a dictionnary

# Iterate on the tr node containted in the table node
for tr_selector in response.selector.xpath('//table//tr'):
     th_text = tr_selector.xpath('./th/text()').extract_first()

     if th_text: # The th node contain text, read the text from the td node
        extracted_values[th_text] = tr_selector.xpath('./td/text()').extract_first()
```

Comment: Hello Clement, thank you very much! I still trying to get used to scrapy and python, so I am very thankful for every helf!